# Producer/Consumer: no producer/consumer should block other producer/consumer

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, software-design

I am designing a system where there will be `n` producers and `m` consumers, where n and m are numbers, and n != m.

I wanted to design the system such a way that,

1. no producer should block other producer when producing
2. no consumer should block other consumer when consuming neither
3. producer nor consumer block each other while producing/consuming

For eg: in java if i use the synchronized key word, then it will be blocking the respective caller.

I am not sure what data structure and algorithm i should use to implement this system.

Can some one provide me help/pointers on this?

Comment: You still will need some sync between actors. You can minimize time of thread blocking by doing as little as possible under a lock (be it `sync` block or usage of explicit `Lock` implementation).

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue will help

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://www.javacodex.com/Concurrency/ConcurrentLinkedQueue-Example). The idea is that you create a single queue. Each of your n producers adds work items to the queue, and each of the m consumers reads work items from the queue. The producer is simply:

```
while not done
    create work item
    add work item to queue
```

The consumer is just as simple:

```
while not done
    get next work item from queue
    process work item
```

The `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` methods handle adding and removing items, synchronizing with the other producers and consumers as required.

The only real drawback is that you have to poll the queue to see if there are items. So you'll probably want an auto reset event that gets tripped whenever an item is added to the queue. For example:

```
add work item to queue
set ItemAvailable event
```

And the consumer would poll the queue and if no item is available, wait on the event:

```
while not done
    while ((item = queue.poll) == null)
        wait on ItemAvailable event
    process item
```

Take a look at the example I linked. It really isn't difficult to use.

Comment: I'd add that CLQ methods are lock-free and wait-free

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much heavy lifting you need to do, and how well your solution need to scale, [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) has a bit of a steep learning curve, but once you got past that it's probably the most elegant, scaling and performing solution.

Run all your producers in different threads, combine them with [`Merg()`](https://speakerdeck.com/benjchristensen/reactive-streams-with-rx-at-javaone-2014?slide=49), move the consumers to there own thread on a unbound buffer with `.observeOn(Scheduler.newThread())`.

---

If you need something that runs well parallel on multiple systems, look at [mapreduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

If you need something at the complete other end of the spectrum (something simple), simply stick to a [ConcurrentQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). That doesn't support multicast, but at least solves the producer side of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want an approach where every action would be atomic and uninterruptible, so yes, in my opinion the best approach would be to use synchronized modifier on methods to set the lock.

The other interesting approach would be to use atomic variables -> http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/09/java-concurrency-atomic-variables.html

That depends on your data in these producer/consumer structures.

Answer (score 0):

use wait() and notify() for thread communication , u can create `n` producer and `m` consumer threads

```
class Q{

 int n;

 boolean value=false;

 synchronized int get() {

 if(!value)

 try  {  wait();   }

 catch(InterruptedException e)

 { System.out.println("thread interrupted"); }

 System.out.println("Got : "+n);

 value=false;

 notify();

 return n;}

 synchronized void put(int n) {

 if(value)

 try { wait();}

 catch(InterruptedException e)

 {  System.out.println("thread interrupted"); }

 this.n=n;

 value=true;

 System.out.println("Put : "+n);

 notify();}}

 class Producer implements Runnable{

 Q q;

 Producer(Q q){

 this.q=q;

  new Thread(this,"Producer").start();}

 public void run(){

 int i=0;

 while(true)

 {

 q.put(i++);}}

 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable{

 Q q;

  Consumer(Q q) {

  this.q=q;

  new Thread(this,"Consumer").start();}

  public void run(){

   while(true)

  {

  q.get();

   }}}

   class PCFixed

  {

   public static void main(String ar[])

  {

   Q q=new Q();

   new Producer(q);

   new Consumer(q);

   System.out.println("PRESS CONTROL-C TO STOP");

   }

   }
```

it goes to infinity, change that based on ur requirements